# Unity3d: Script changes value of property but nothing happens

Tags: c#, networking, properties, callback, unity-game-engine

I have set a public property of type Mode (a enum) "mode" for my GameObject's GameManager Monobehaviour, however sometimes, specially on callbacks, asigning a value to said property doesn't do anything:

For example:

```
public class GameManager : uLink.MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameManager instance;

    public bool dedicated = false;
    public Mode mode = Mode.MainMenu;
    public List<Player> players = new List<Player> ();
    public Player localPlayer;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        GameManager.instance = this;
    }

    #region Server
        #region Network

    void uLink_OnServerInitialized ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("Server successfully started on port " + uLink.Network.listenPort);
        new Authenticator ("127.0.0.1", 1234, "DB", "dbUser", "dbPassword");
        mode = Mode.ServerDone;
    }
    (...)
    public enum Mode
    {
        MainMenu, //
        ServerInit, //Server start
        ServerStarting, //Server is starting
        ServerDone, //Server done loading
        ClientInit, //Client starting up
        ClientConnected, //Client connected
        ClientAwaitAuth,
        ClientAuthed, //Client authenticated
        ClientAuthFailed,
        Client //Client mode
    }
}
```

(This happens both when using Unity3D's network and uLink's network)

The callback happens and the Log is placed on the console, the authenticator singleton is created too, but the mode doesn't change. I've tried debugging and placing a breakpoint on `mode = Mode.ServerDone;` but it then just says "Value not loaded"

My code works perfectly if I then manually change the mode to `Mode.ServerDone` using the editor.

My best guess is that this happens because the callback is called by a coroutine that doesn't have the ability to write on the property, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: How did you declare your `Mode` enum? Do you have that code somewhere?

Comment: Didn't thought that would matter, added it to the question

Comment: I was just wondering if you actually declared the `Mode`, but you did. It seems to be ok so it might be the case that your `Enum` function isn't loaded yet, when you declare `mode`. Perhaps you should give `mode` his initial value in `Start()` or even `OnLevelWasLoaded`.

Comment: Mode is being loaded, it is infact being edited before the callback is called. It goes from `MainMenu` to `ServerInit` and then to `ServerStarting` properlly, but when its time to change it to `ServerDone` inside the `OnServerInitialized()` callback, it doesn't change. If I change it manually it then goes from `ClientInit` to `ClientConnected` and `ClientAwaitAuth` propperlly (It simulates a client connection) but doesnt change to `ClientAuthed` when the `OnAuthenticateSuccess()` callback. If I then modify it using the editor to `ClientAuthed` it goes to `Client` propperlly and the game starts

Comment: Ok, then it seems to be coded well. I'm kind of confused about the "Value not loaded"-part. Is `mode` `null`?

Comment: This is what I mean: http://puu.sh/2Lh8c.png

Comment: That's some strange behaviour I'm seeing.. I'm actually clueless about what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, turns out StartServer() is not async therefore my mode was getting replaced.